# Can we use client-side angularjs routing using ui router with expressjs server side routing in nodejs. Below is the example

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

Example:

```
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var fs=require('fs');
var express=require("express");
var myApp = express();
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert=require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname';
var ObjectId=MongoClient.ObjectID;
var http=require('http');

myApp.use(express.static("."));
myApp.use(bodyparser.json());
myApp.listen(5000);
```

I am using server(apache or node) to load only index file from there after am using ui-router to make it a SPA which is working well wen run in apache server but this is not working wen ran on node:

the index is being loaded correctly but following url :
http://localhost:5000/Test/#/dashboard
 throws the message : "Cannot GET /Test/" in node server, How to make the Routing to work correctly in expressjs

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

```
var DASHBOARD_ROOT = 'templates';
```

$stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'employeeInfoCtrl'
    });

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
    abstract :true,
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    controller: 'employeeInfoCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('dashboard.home',{
    url:'',
    templateUrl: DASHBOARD_ROOT +'/Home.html'
});
$stateProvider.state('dashboard.about',{
    url:'/about',
    templateUrl: DASHBOARD_ROOT +'/about.html'
});
$stateProvider.state('dashboard.employeeinfo',{
  url:'/employeeinfo',
  templateUrl:DASHBOARD_ROOT+'/employeeinfo.html'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In node : you have to add path `GET#test`

```
myApp.get('/test',function(req,resp){

    resp.render('index.html');
})
```

Comment: Hi Ritchie, its not working,throwing : Error: Cannot find module 'html'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)....

Comment: The index file is being loaded correctly, but on login am replacing the view, using uirouter only which is not happening

Comment: @BhimashankarMantur same way u have to write login route for login.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by targeting your client build directory with

```
app.use(express.static('dist')) //dist is where your js is bundled
```

then redirect all the requests using wildcard (*) to your index.html file

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html')));
```

Comment: not working  i want only client side routing using uirouter but expressjs is coming inbetween, seems hve to set the viewEngine.

Comment: @BhimashankarMantur what do you mean by express "inbetween" your client router and your views ? 
If you do not render views with express you do not need to setup a view engine.

Comment: am configuring routing using angulars uirouter but express is not allowing tat configuration to work, i want to use express only for getting and posting the data